Woocommerce REST API: enable basic auth through HTTP for local development
I'm running a Wordpress instance (Docker) in my local Dev machine and I would like to perform HTTP requests to the Woocommerce API like in the production server (that runs on HTTPS). If I just create a key/secret pair, as the Docker image runs on HTTP, I keep receiving a 401 error indicating that I can't list resources. I've digged on it and seems to be that Basic auth is only enabled for HTTPS requests but, is there a way to make it work in a local Docker Wordpress so I can test it like in the actual production environment?
I've tried using an Nginx image as a proxy but I have the same issue and I've also tried to hack the Woocommerce authentication in the plugin source code (and I probably didn't find the right place).

authentication can be made by application password, it's managed by the core : https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/

Thanks, @mmm! That certanily helped. Using the app password and adding a custom filter (as explained in the article you link) to enable it through HTTP worked.
